# What is the default spring AOP aspect for all methods all packages and functions?

Tags: spring-aop

Help me with below spring aop expression , not sure what is wrong here

**@Before("execution(* *(..)")** is not working

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question topic the requirement here is to advice the execution of all the public methods of beans across the application. Following pointcut expression would achieve the same.

```
execution(public * *(..))
```

Please be aware that the above expressoin is for sure to have undesired results. This is because the scope of this expression is for all the spring application context managed beans , which includes the framework beans as well.

A better approach would be to target only the beans from your application , an example would be

```
 execution(* com.xyz.service..*.*(..))
```

This pointcut targets execution of any method defined in the service package or one of its sub-packages

Both examples are taken from the Spring reference documentation - [AOP pointcut examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-examples)

Recommended reading.

- [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop)
- [Writing good pointcuts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#writing-good-pointcuts)